# How to get access token for Azure DevOps and use this for DevOps services REST APIs call?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

Actually I want to get the **list** of "**Azure Pipeline**" using JavaScript REST API. Please check below for the REST API url:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Now to get the response we need to pass the "access token". As of now I'm getting the access token using the "**@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth**" library, but as a response I'm not getting the proper response. Please check the below code.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
     let url = `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1`;
     const header = {
         Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`   // I got the "token" using the "**@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth**" library
     };
     const result = await rp({
          url: url,
          json: true,
          headers: header,
          mode: 'cors',
          cache: 'no-cache',
          method: 'GET'
     });
     context.res = {
          body: result
     };
}
```

After using the above code I'm not getting the proper response, getting the response as HTML.

**So can anyone please tell me that how do I get the proper access token for DevOps services REST APIs call or How do I get the list of Azure devpos pipeline using JavaScript or Node Js ???**

Comment: It would be useful for you to show more code.  Also to include console.log output of values (you can sanitize sensitive information in them). I've not used the library to which you're referring, but one thing I would check is to ensure that the token value is Base64-encoded before setting the Authorization header in your request.

Comment: Hi WaitingForGuacamole, Please check here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69270077/how-to-get-azure-devops-pipelines-list-with-the-help-of-msal-using-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get the token. Not sure how to get the access token via [@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth/v/3.0.10)
, to get the access token via AAD auth to call Azure DevOps REST API, make sure you are using a user-involved flow e.g. auth code flow, device code flow, etc, as the client credential flow(use service principal or MSI to auth) will not work with Azure DevOps REST API.

For example, you could use the [device-code flow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth/v/3.0.10).

```
import * as msRestNodeAuth from "@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth";

msRestNodeAuth.interactiveLoginWithAuthResponse().then((authres) => {
  console.dir(authres, { depth: null })
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

You could also use auth code flow to get the token via [ADAL for Node.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs#authorization-code).

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var clientId = 'yourClientIdHere';
var clientSecret = 'yourAADIssuedClientSecretHere'
var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.windows.net';
var tenant = 'myTenant';
var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
var redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/getAToken';
var resource = '499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798';
var templateAuthzUrl = 'https://login.windows.net/' + 
                        tenant + 
                        '/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=' +
                        clientId + 
                        '&redirect_uri=' + 
                        redirectUri + 
                        '&state=<state>&resource=' + 
                        resource;

function createAuthorizationUrl(state) {
  return templateAuthzUrl.replace('<state>', state);
}

// Clients get redirected here in order to create an OAuth authorize url and redirect them to AAD.
// There they will authenticate and give their consent to allow this app access to
// some resource they own.
app.get('/auth', function(req, res) {
  crypto.randomBytes(48, function(ex, buf) {
    var token = buf.toString('base64').replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');

    res.cookie('authstate', token);
    var authorizationUrl = createAuthorizationUrl(token);

    res.redirect(authorizationUrl);
  });
});

// After consent is granted AAD redirects here.  The ADAL library is invoked via the
// AuthenticationContext and retrieves an access token that can be used to access the
// user owned resource.
app.get('/getAToken', function(req, res) {
  if (req.cookies.authstate !== req.query.state) {
    res.send('error: state does not match');
  }

  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

  authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode(
    req.query.code,
    redirectUri,
    resource,
    clientId, 
    clientSecret,
    function(err, response) {
      var errorMessage = '';
      if (err) {
        errorMessage = 'error: ' + err.message + '\n';
      }
      errorMessage += 'response: ' + JSON.stringify(response);
      res.send(errorMessage);
    }
  );
});
```

You could also use the [MSAL for node.js auth code flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/auth-code) to get the token, it is an update for ADAL, remember to change the scope to devops `"scopes": ["499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"]`.

Comment: Hi Joy, thank you for your response. We can not use "ADAL" library for DevOps REST API call. To call DevOps REST API we should use "MSAL".  I have used the MSAL for node but still I am unable to get the Azure DevOps Pipelines list. Please check below url for my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69270077/how-to-get-azure-devops-pipelines-list-with-the-help-of-msal-using-nodejs

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops